# Linux: test expression

Tags: linux, man, if

How to use `test` to test a expression like this:

```
if { [ $month -eq 03 ] || [ $month -eq 10 ]; } && [ $weekday = "So" ] && [ $day -gt 24 ]
```

I need to test the whole if statement in a single row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Purely POSIX `test` or `[` cannot test this with exactly one invocation of the tool. The way you did it is how it should be done with POSIX `[`. Why do you think it's not good for you and you need "a single row"?

Comment: No need a single row, but how to test the whole expression?

Comment: From the first `{` to the last `]` your expression is syntactically valid, if only the variables expand to sane values. It tests *something*. If it doesn't behave as you expect then maybe you got the logic wrong; or the `if` statement; or where you define the variables. Please [edit] and post a [complete example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367021/10765659). What do you expect from it? How does it fail? What shell are you using to run this?

Comment: Hint: code that depends on the current time and date can be tested with `faketime`. Compare `faketime '1999-01-02 12:34:56' date`. Just use your script instead of `date` to see how the script behaves at the chosen moment in the past or in the future. See `man 1 faketime`.

Comment: How to use `test`: give the expression as arguments and `echo $?` afterwards.